# Getting Last Cookie Expiration

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
    cookie_name = "Counter_Cookie";

    function doCookie() {

        if(document.cookie) {
            index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
        } 

        else {
            index = -1;
            alert("Welcome the site! Please don't forget to bookmark this page!");  
        }

        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);

        if (index == -1) {
            document.cookie = cookie_name + "=1; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        } 

        else {
            countbegin = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
            countend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
            if (countend == -1) {
                countend = document.cookie.length;
            }

            count = eval(document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend)) + 1;

            document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+count+"; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        }

        document.write("<p>You have been to my site "+getTimes()+".</p>");
    }


    function getTimes() {

        if(document.cookie) {
            index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
            if (index != -1) {
            countbegin = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
            countend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
                if (countend == -1) {
                    countend = document.cookie.length;
                }
                count = document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend);
                if (count == 1) {
                    return (count+" time");
                } 
                else {
                    return (count+" times");
                }
            }
        }
        return ("0 times");

    }
```

I want to know how to get the last cookies expiration date to show the last time the person visited the site. I'm assuming I'll need an array but, I can't seem to find out how to do that with the code I've written.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft says: "The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies. Therefore, although you can read the name and value of a cookie, you cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time. When the browser sends cookie information to the server, the browser does not include the expiration information." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx

So you can append `expire` timestamp with separator into cookie's value: `count + '|' + expires.getTime()`

Then parse time in `getTimes()`:

```
data = document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend).split('|');
count = data[0];
expirationDate = new Date();
expirationDate.setTime(data[1]);
```

Whole code:

```
cookie_name = "Counter_Cookie";

function doCookie() {

    if(document.cookie) {
        index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
    } 

    else {
        index = -1;
        alert("Welcome the site! Please don't forget to bookmark this page!");  
    }

    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);

    if (index == -1) {
        document.cookie = cookie_name + "=1|" + expires.getTime() + "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    } 

    else {
        countbegin = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
        countend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
        if (countend == -1) {
            countend = document.cookie.length;
        }

        count = eval(document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend)) + 1;

        document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+count+"|" + expires.getTime() + "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    }

    document.write("<p>You have been to my site "+getTimes()+".</p>");
}


function getTimes() {

    if(document.cookie) {
        index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
        if (index != -1) {
        countbegin = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
        countend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
            if (countend == -1) {
                countend = document.cookie.length;
            }
            data = document.cookie.substring(countbegin, countend).split('|');
            count = data[0];
            date = new Date();
            date.setTime(data[1]);
            if (count == 1) {
                message = count+" time";
            } 
            else {
                message = count+" times";
            }

            return message + ", last expire: " + date.toUTCString();
        }
    }
    return ("0 times");
}
```